# Break from block based on time

Tags: ruby

I would like to run a block for 60 seconds.  What I have come up with thus far does not break out of the block as desired.

```
@start_time = Time.now
stream_some_data do |x| 
  # .. do something ...
  break if Time.now == @start_time + 60
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're unlikely to get to that line at *exactly* 60 seconds past the start, try:

```
break if Time.now > @start_time + 60
```

Comment: I used a counter within the block that incremented by one each time.  Break worked when I used: break if counter == (some number)

Comment: Oh! My bad. You probably just want `break if Time.now > @start_time + 60`, then.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby's stdlib already has a Timeout module for this:

```
begin
  require "timeout"
  Timeout::timeout(60) do
    # all of the things...
  end
rescue Timeout::Error => e
end
```

Comment: It could be done with this, though after every 60 seconds it is going to run rescue. I want to call another method after the 60 seconds and can do this with: rescue run_the_next_method.  But this doesn't seem to use 'timeout' as it was intended to be used!

Comment: I used to think the same way as you do, but I'm getting more and more used to Ruby errors just being half-errors and half system messages. I wouldn't see anything wrong even with running rescue 60 times per second.